# AngularJS manual injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think I must have read the tutorial incorrectly, but I just can't seem to get manual injection working correctly on my project.

I'm about to minify and mangle my js so I thought I'd go through the process of manually injecting all my modules and controllers, but I'm getting errors stating that the providers don't exist.

Here's an example of what I'm trying achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/apuN8/5/

```
angular
    .module('manual.injection', [])
    .config($injector.invoke(['$provide', function ($provide) {
        // I can't get this far
    }]));
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I don't need to use the $injector object at all. I simply pass an array to my config/directives/filters etc:

```
angular
    .module('manual.injection', [])
    .config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
        // Ta-da
    }]);
```

Comment: You don't even need the array. With only the function its argument will be injected as well. You only need the array describing the injected resource if your code gets minified.

Comment: The problem I was having though, was when the code gets minified before production release. So the code would become mangled and look something like:

    `angular.module('manual.injection',[]).config(function(t){//do stuff})`

This obviously breaks because there's no provider called `t`.